# Wordpress admin page editing width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

My client did a wordpress update and realized the admin page editor changed to a really reduced width while doing bloc editing :

[image]

Since he handles a table that is wider than the screen, this doesn't work for his.

Is there a way to widen the view to the available screen width?

Thanks

Comment: Augustin, I've had a quick look at the css and there are multiple places that one would have to change I think.   You could try adding back the classic editor (https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) for now (although after last wp update, I'm having trouble switching between the two editors in localhost(stuck in classic unless I deactivate).  I havent analysed that yet ( classic works)

Comment: Sadly even 'full screen' mode editing in the block doesn't make the 'block' wide enough, nor does using the 'table block'

Comment: FYI.  Deactivated and reactivated classic editor (after also deactivating all other plugins) and now I can switch happily between the two, so perhaps that's a good solution for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as frm the screenshot that the wordpress is upgraded to version 5 or above in which Guttenberg editor comes as default. However you can add below [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) into it that will help you to get the screen as it is

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Block Editor Full Width 
 * Description: Fix the block editor width to full size
 */

add_action('admin_head', 'block_editor_full_width');

function block_editor_full_width() {
  echo '<style>
  .wp-block {
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: none !important;}
  .editor-styles-wrapper .editor-writing-flow {  
      max-width: none !important;
      margin: 0 !important;}
}
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried this because I'm more comfortable using a plugin, that will be upgraded and can be easily deactivated.

Comment: The above is a plugin that can be deactivated.  Put it in your plugin directory with suitable file name.Note: Not all plugins get maintained.   This one https://wordpress.org/support/topic/try-this-revised-code/ used to work when the block editor was called 'gutenberg'. Probably still works for wp sites < 5.0 that have gutenberg installed.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Anyway, the classic-editor plugin did the job for me. :)

Comment: Well that's interesting - the accepted answer is basically my comment from the day before, and my answer which more directly answered the actual question was downvoted.